# Prevent <form> line break between two <form> tags

Tags: html, css

I want to prevent line breaks between two forms I have.

So basically:

```
<form action="...">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
LINE BREAK HERE
<form action="...">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I want to **remove** the line break. I want the input buttons to be on the same line, like a menu.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
form {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me... I only have one <form> tag, and there is still a line break BEFORE it (the line break after is removed by the style declaration). Hmm...

Comment: <form style='display: inline;'>   works for me - if you still get blanks, maybe move the form tag right up next to the first form element.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is the correct solution:

```
form { display: inline-block; }
```

The inline-block value is used for the purpose of laying out native block-level elements inline. Those elements will still remain blocks.

Changing the model for an element from block to inline is a radical move because it may mess things up depending on what the contents of the element are.

For this particular issue, using inline-block is the way to go.

Comment: This still adds whitespace (less than without, but it's not all gone)

Comment: @cnd Why is that a problem? You want a space between the `<input>`s.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread, so I probably am not helping anyone, but here is my suggestion.  Many programmers avoid tables and therefore do not like my method, but I solve this problem as follows:

```
<table><tr><td><form></form></td><td><form></form></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or:

```
form {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If display:inline isn't working, it might be because a parent element has a width that is too small to hold both next to each other, and that can cause the form elements to break onto separate lines. Try adding this rule to the style for the container that holds the two forms:

`white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

This only worked for me when I put `< form style="display: inline-block;"/>` directly into the html.  When I tried putting it into the style sheet:

```
.form
{display: inline-block;}
```

it didn't work.  I had to put it into the html.

Comment: This is because you've used a class selector (the `.`). Either add a `class="form"`into the `<form>` tag or remove the selector and just use `form {display: inline-block;}`