# How to avoid line wrap in a form generated with typescript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a ReactJS project. The goal is simple: **I want all three `<FormItem>` appear in one single line, without wrap.** Instead, I obtain an output as follows:

[image: Screenshot]

In `myComponent.tsx` I have the following `render()` function:

```
render() {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
  const formItemLayoutType = {
          labelCol: { span: 1, offset: 0 },
          wrapperCol: { span: 3, offset: 0 },
  };
  const myForm = {
         display: "inline",
         whiteSpace: "nowrap"
  } as React.CSSProperties;

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} style={myForm}>
     <span>
      <FormItem 
       // {...formItemLayoutType}  // originally, this was not commented out
       hasFeedback
      >
         {getFieldDecorator('select', { valuePropName: "fileType" })(
                        <Select placeholder="Select file type" style={{ width: "150px" }}>
                            <Option value="PD">Probabilty of default</Option>
                            <Option value="FX">Exchange Rate</Option>
                        </Select>
                        )}
      </FormItem>
      <FormItem>
         <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit"
                 disabled={this.disabledImportButtonChecker()}>Import</Button>
      </FormItem>
     </span>
    </Form>
  );
 }
}
```

I added the `<span>` and the `style={myForm}`, the rest of the code is historic. I just cannot figure out why it still looks as follows rather than everything horizontally arranged.

#### References

- [Prevent <form> line break between two <form> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854682/prevent-form-line-break-between-two-form-tags)  suggests to use `display: inline`.
- https://alligator.io/css/prevent-line-break/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `<span>` to a `<div>`, and give it a style of `display: flex;`

See example (I added the style inline for simplicity, you should place it the way you do all your styles)

```
//** inline style for simplicity **//
<span style={{display:"flex"}}>
    <FormItem 
        // {...formItemLayoutType}  // originally, this was not commented out
        hasFeedback
    >
        {getFieldDecorator('select', { valuePropName: "fileType" })(
            <Select placeholder="Select file type" style={{ width: "150px" }}>
                <Option value="PD">Probabilty of default</Option>
                <Option value="FX">Exchange Rate</Option>
            </Select>
        )}
    </FormItem>
    <FormItem>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit"
            disabled={this.disabledImportButtonChecker()}>Import</Button>
    </FormItem>
</span>
```